# Will a non official Arduino work with the arduin IDE

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I want to buy an Arduino kit but not an official Arduino, from different company

My question is: Will it work with the Arduino IDE?
Even if it not official?

Can I use Python with it?

Comment: sure is, you can't use Python with Arduino IDE. You can use Python on some Arduinos. doesn't matter if original or clone. Most Arduinos in use are not originals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arduino** is an open-source hardware and software project, **Arduino IDE** supports many Arduino-compatible boards, including official and non-official boards, here is a non-exhaustive [list of compatible boards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems).

You can even make your own Arduino-compatible board and provide hardware platform/plugins for Arduino IDE.